# I am trying to implement infinite scroll in my react/redux application but the Get More Posts function is executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, infinite-scroll

On my Home Page Component, I am trying to implement infinite scroll with a scroll event listener. I load the first set of posts in componentDidMount, then when I get near the bottom of the page, I want to execute a redux action which calls my API and gets the next set of posts.

However, I can see via console logs that the redux actions is executing a bunch of times. I set up an '<hr' tag at the bottom of the page and am using that to identify when i get to the bottom of the page.

Here is the code on my Home Component:

```
class home extends Component {
state = {
    scrolling: false,
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPostsInfinite();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = (e) => {
    console.log('scrolling');
    const { scrolling } = this.state;
    if (scrolling) return;
    const lastElement = document.getElementById('scrollEnd');
    const lastElementOffset = lastElement.offsetTop + lastElement.clientHeight;
    const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
    const bottomOffset = 100;
    if (pageOffset > lastElementOffset - bottomOffset) this.onButtonClick();
};

onButtonClick = () => {
    this.props.getPostsInfiniteNext({
        lastVisible: this.props.data.lastVisible,
    });
};

render() {
    const { posts, loading } = this.props.data;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let recentPostsMarkup = !loading ? (
        posts.map((post) => {
            return <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />;
        })
    ) : (
        <div className={classes.progressContainerPosts}>
            <CircularProgress />
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Grid container spacing={10} id="grid">
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <Profile />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    <CreatePostForm />
                    {recentPostsMarkup}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <hr id="scrollEnd" />
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Here is the function to get the next set of posts

```
    export const getPostsInfiniteNext = (lastVisible) => (dispatch) => {
    console.log('get next set of posts running');
    axios
        .post('/posts/infinite/next', lastVisible)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS_NEXT,
                payload: res.data,
            });
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LAST_VISIBLE,
                payload: res.data,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: [],
            });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

May be calculation issue in handleScroll which might be resulting in this.onButtonClick method getting fired. Also scrolling state variable is never set to true.